# To call a function from a class, does Python iterate through every function the class has until it finds the function to call?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, class

For example, let's say I have this:

```py
class RandomFunctions:
    def function_1:
        print('function 1 calling')

    def function_2:
        print('function_2 activated')

    def function_3:
        print('function_3 activated')

    def function_4:
        print('function_4 activated')

RandomFunctions().function_4()
```

To call `function_4`, does Python iterate through every other function in the class, checking if it's the right function, or directly calls it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`function_4` is a class attribute whose name is stored in an object that implements the mapping protocol. Lookup is done by direct indexing of that object. There is no iteration involved, and the order in which the functions are defined is largely irrelevant.

```
>>> type(RandomeFunctions.__dict__)
<class 'mappingproxy'>
>>> RandomFunctions.__dict__['function_4'] is RandomFunctions.function_4
True
```

Comment: Interesting! Though the experiment in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62159173/11228943) shows that the function, the farther up it is in the class, the longer it takes to execute. How is that possible?

Comment: The `mappingproxy` class is basically just a read-only wrapper around a `dict` that prevents you from updating it. Any variation in the time it takes to access one element or the other appears to be due to the behavior of the underlying hash table, not any direct iteration of its elements.

Answer (score -1):

I did a little experiment, here is the result:

```
from time import perf_counter

class RandomFunctions: # Defines 20000 functions
    for n in range(20000):
        exec(f"""def function_{n}(self):
            print(f'function {n} calling')""")

a = RandomFunctions()
start = perf_counter()
a.function_0() # Calls first function
end = perf_counter()
print(end-start)
```

Output:

```
function 0 calling
0.03125423399999949
```

#

```
start = perf_counter()
a.function_1999() # Calls the 1999th function
end = perf_counter()
print(end-start)
```

Output:

```
function 1999 calling
0.0849990759999999
```

The conclusion of this experiment appears to be that:

*The class does iterate through the functions to find the right one.*

Comment: That is very very little data for any conclusion.

Comment: I cannot reproduce these timings - both are roughly equally fast (``0.00012`` vs. ``0.00011``). Note that your timings are only single data points, *and* include the instantiation of ``RandomFunctions`` as well. Consider to use a proper benchmarking tool, such as ``pyperf`` or ``timeit``. Consider to remove the ``RandomFunctions`` instantiation from the timing, or separately benchmark the instantiation to subtract it from the combined test.